# Porting Java to Apex: libphonenumber

Tags: validation, data, java, softphone

To perform back-end validation and formatting of phone numbers, I am interested in porting the Java version of Google's open-source [libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) library to Apex. If you have ported a Java library to Apex, can you offer general advice on tools to use, gotchas to watch out for or other things you've learned?

Comment: Have you tried this ? https://github.com/kumarrk21/ZPhoneFormatter

Comment: That might work if phone is accepted interactively. Many times phone info comes in APIs or you need to scrub old data then Lightning component will not work.

Scott, I believe with sufficient time, it is possible to port to Apex but it can be daunting task. Considering there is huge data set you need to process for each formatting.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the nifty Lightning Component Sagar! It's a good start for on-demand formatting, and could be extended to validate numbers and even geocode or find time zone using other modules of libphonenumber. As you note in the blog post, though, the size of the library poses an obstacle for on-demand use.

Comment: Did you ever complete this?  Would love to find an open source apex port.

Comment: No, rather than porting the library to Apex, we built a Lightning component to validate on-demand.

Comment: We have ported the [libphonenumber](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000G12oJUAR) library to Salesforce (Apex) and it's available for free on the App Exchange. In case you have any issues or need some help don't hesitate to contact me or our team at [Noltic](https://noltic.com/).